# Illustration of conditional distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The question is devoted to some basic probability theory.

Imagine the following procedure: we throw a point $X_1$ into the segment $[0,1]$ (we mean that $X_1$ is uniformly distributed). After that we choose the longer of two parts $[0,X_1]$ or $[X_1,1]$ and also "break" it randomly into two parts: thus, $X_2$ is distributed uniformly in $[0,X_1]$ or $[X_1,1]$.

How can I get the distribution of $X_2$? Can I use the formula
$$f_{X_2}(x)=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X_2|X_1}(x\,|\,y)\cdot f_{X_1}(y)\,dy,\,\,\,$$
where $f_{X_2|X_1}(x\,|\,y)$ is the conditional pdf of $X_2$ given $X_1=y$? If so, why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it obvious, or it is derived from the formula, that I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1\sim U(0,1)$, then $X_2$ has conditional density
$$f_{X_2\mid X_1}(x_2\mid x_1) = \frac1{1-x_1}\mathsf 1_{\left(0,\frac12\right)}(x_1)\mathsf 1_{(x_1,1)}(x_2) + \frac1{x_1}\mathsf 1_{\left(\frac12,1\right)}(x_1)\mathsf 1_{(0,x_1)}(x_2). $$
Note that
$$\mathsf 1_{\left(0,\frac12\right)}(x_1)\mathsf 1_{(x_1,1)}(x_2)= \mathsf 1_{\left(0,\frac12\right)}(x_2)\mathsf 1_{(0,x_2)}(x_1) + \mathsf 1_{\left(\frac12,1\right)}(x_2)\mathsf 1_{\left(0,\frac12\right)}(x_1)$$ and
$$\mathsf 1_{\left(\frac12,1\right)}(x_1)\mathsf 1_{(0,x_1)}(x_2) = \mathsf 1_{\left(0,\frac12\right)}(x_2)\mathsf 1_{(x_2,1)}(x_1) + \mathsf 1_{\left(\frac12,1\right)}(x_2)\mathsf 1_{\left(\frac12,1\right)}(x_1), $$
so
\begin{align}
f_{X_2\mid X_1}(x_2\mid x_1) =& \left(\frac1{1-x_1}\mathsf 1_{(0,x_2)}(x_1) + \frac1{x_1}\mathsf 1_{\left(\frac12,1\right)}(x_1)  \right)\mathsf 1_{\left(0,\frac12\right)}(x_2)\\
+& \left(\frac1{1-x_1}\mathsf 1_{\left(0,\frac12\right)}(x_1) + \frac1{x_1}\mathsf 1_{(x_2,1)}(x_1)  \right)\mathsf 1_{\left(\frac12,1\right)}(x_2).
\end{align}
The marginal density of $X_2$ is obtained by computing
\begin{align}
f_{X_2}(x_2) 
&= \int_{\mathbb R} f_{X_2\mid X_1}(x_1\mid x_2)f_{X_1}(x_1)\ \mathsf dx_1\\
&= \left[\int_{\mathbb R} \left(\frac1{1-x_1}\mathsf 1_{(0,x_2)}(x_1) + \frac1{x_1}\mathsf 1_{\left(\frac12,1\right)}(x_1)  \right)\ \mathsf dx_1\right] \mathsf 1_{\left(0,\frac12\right)}(x_2)\\
&\quad+\left[\int_{\mathbb R}\left(\frac1{1-x_1}\mathsf 1_{\left(0,\frac12\right)}(x_1) + \frac1{x_1}\mathsf 1_{(x_2,1)}(x_1)  \right)\ \mathsf dx_1\right]\mathsf 1_{\left(\frac12,1\right)}(x_2)\\
&=\left[\int_0^{x_2}\frac1{1-x_1}\ \mathsf dx_1+\int_{\frac12}^1\frac1{x_1}\ \mathsf dx_1 \right]\mathsf 1_{\left(0,\frac12\right)}(x_2)\\
&\quad+\left[\int_0^{\frac12}\frac1{1-x_1}\ \mathsf dx_1+\int_{x_2}^1\frac1{x_1}\ \mathsf dx_1 \right]\mathsf 1_{\left(\frac12,1\right)}(x_2)\\
&= \log\left(\frac2{1-x_2}\right)\mathsf 1_{\left(0,\frac12\right)}(x_2) + \log\left(\frac2{x_2}\right)\mathsf 1_{\left(\frac12,1\right)}(x_2).
\end{align}